# Visual Studio failed to enter debug mode due to error finding parse tree node for active statement

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I just update my project from a repository and since that when my program hits a debug point, it gives me this message:

> Entering break mode failed for the following reason: Error finding
>   parse tree node for active statement.      Usually, this condition
>   occurs when the project was not rebuilt prior to starting the
>   debugging session, when the assembly file for the project is out of
>   date, or when the project source files were moved to a different disk
>   location between the time the project was built and the debugging
>   session was started.     Edit and Continue will be disabled for this
>   debugging session.

I cleaned and rebuilt many times, updated to previous revision, deleted the bin and obj directory, the suo files, so far no luck. What could cause this? What should I check?